# Factoring the $L$-function of the Eisenstein series of a non-primitive character.

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, modular-forms

Let $\chi$ be an odd Dirichlet character modulo $N$. Let $E_{1,\chi}\in M_1(N,\chi)$ be the (normalized) weight 1 Eisenstein series of $\chi$. If $\chi$ is primitive, this series has $q$-expansion
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
E_{1,\chi}(z)=\frac{ L(\chi,0)}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{d|n}\chi(d)\right)q^n,
\end{equation}
where $q=e^{2\pi i z}$. In this case, we can see explicitly that $L$-function of $E_{1,\chi}$ factors into a product of classical $L$-functions, namely
\begin{align*}
L(E_{1,\chi},s) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{d|n}\chi(d)\right) n^{-s}\\
&= \sum_{a=1}^\infty \sum_{b=1}^\infty \chi(a) (ab)^{-s}\\
&= \left(\sum_{a=1}^\infty \chi(a)a^{-s}\right) \left(\sum_{b=1}^\infty b^{-s}\right)\\
&= L(\chi,s)\zeta(s).
\end{align*}

Now, when $\chi$ is not primitive, one can still consider the Eisenstein series $E_{1,\chi}$, however, the $q$-expansion is given by the more complicated formula
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
E_{1,\chi}(z)=-\frac{NL(\bar{\chi},1)}{2\pi i\,\tau(\bar{\chi}')}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{d|n}\sum_{r|(d,h)}\mu\Big(\frac{h}{r}\Big)\bar{\chi}'\Big(\frac{h}{r}\Big)\chi'\Big(\frac{d}{r}\Big) r  \right)q^n,
\end{equation}
where $\chi'$ is the primitive character of $\chi$ modulo its conductor $N'$, and $h=N/N'$ (this formula is taken from Miyake's book titled "*Modular Forms*", Theorem 7.2.13).

**My question is:** What happens to the $L$-function of $E_{1,\chi}$ when $\chi$ is not primitive? Can we still factor $L(E_{1,\chi},s)$ in this case?

In all the literature I have come across, factorizations such as this are handled only for primitive characters. Nonetheless, it seems (to me at least) that it should still be possible to factor for general $\chi$. Perhaps we would miss a few Euler factors or introduce an explicit error, and that is ok.

I have tried to manipulate the summations inside the coefficients in (2) to make it work, but I failed. The $a_n$ in (2) are way more complicated to rearrange than the ones in (1). I may be missing something.

Also, if someone knows a reference for these kinds of factorizations when $\chi$ is not primitive, it would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Look at Matt Young's paper in JNT on Eisenstein series; I think this is done there. In any case, these kinds of calculations are still *doable* in the imprimitive case, but there is no *reason* for why one should do this. $L$-functions really are associated to *newforms*, and if $\chi$ is imprimitive, $E_{1,\chi}$ is not a newform.

Comment: @PeterHumphries I checked Matthew Young's paper titled "Explicit calculations with Eisenstein series". It contains a lot of very useful information concerning Eisenstein series of non-primitive characters. Thank you for the reference!! Unfortunately, he does not discuss the factorization of the $L$-function of Eisenstein series.

Comment: In the specific situation in which I am working, I have a group ring element $\theta\in\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}^\times]$ and I am trying to prove a certain statement for $\theta$. In the end, the statement boils down to showing that a formula holds for $\chi(\theta)$ for every $\chi$ modulo $N$ (because this completely determines $\theta$). So, I really need to work with every character modulo $N$. In this process the $L$-function of non-primitive Eisenstein series shows up.